# GridView:'Object' does not contain a definition for

Tags: c#, webforms, visual-studio-2015

I have 2 error messages with my c# webform, that i can not handle by myself.

Add.aspx:

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Add.aspx.cs" Inherits="keszlet_management.Add" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <p>
            <br />
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
        </p>
    </asp:Content>
```

Add.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page

{
    public object GridView1 { get; private set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM items"))
                {
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I am new in C#, so I know i have several mistakes, please focus on error messages:
1.: Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'DataSource' and no extension method 'DataSource' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2.: The same message with 'DataBind'

Comment: You've defined `GridView1` as type `object` and `object` does not have those methods/properties.  Perhaps you should define it as `GridView` or try doing a cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have declared your `GridView` as

```
public object GridView1 { get; private set; }
```

It is a `GridView` so don't declare it as object, otherwise you can't use the properties or methods of a `GridView` but only of `System.Object`, or you have to cast it to `GridView`.

Since this is a codebehind file of an aspx file **you don't need to declare it at all**. It will be auto generated in the partial class that has the same name and ends with `.designer.cs`.

Answer (score 1):

On this line: `public object GridView1 { get; private set; }`. Shouldn't it be declared as GridView instead of just object? Check out the example usage here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx